# How to run a 3 month sum of rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cumulative-sum

I am trying to replicate this behavior in SQL Server 2014. I have total dollars being worked per month, but I want a new column that takes the dollars and sums it by the current and next 2 months and places the total in the current month row. How can I accomplish this with SQL server?

```
Date      Dollars   3 MONTH SUM
1/1/2018    10      37
2/1/2018    12      32
3/1/2018    15      36
4/1/2018    5       36
5/1/2018    16      34
6/1/2018    15      23
7/1/2018    3       27
8/1/2018    5       40
9/1/2018    19      46
10/1/2018   16      27
11/1/2018   11      11
```

I tried:

```
SUM(dollars) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN current row and 2 following) AS [3 month sum]
```

but the calculation wasn't accurate. Is this the proper way to do it and I am just not doing it correctly or is there a better method?

Comment: Could you provide yours expect results?

Comment: actually, I just figured out what was going on. the dates were not all present. some months were missing. my solution actually worked well.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, and look very simple to read

```
declare @Incomings table([Date] Datetime, Dollars int)
insert into @Incomings
values
('20180101', 10)
,('20180201', 12)
,('20180301', 15)
,('20180401', 5)
,('20180501', 16)
,('20180601', 15)
,('20180701', 3)
,('20180801', 5)
,('20180901', 19)
,('20181001', 16)
,('20181101', 11)


select * , (select SUM(Dollars) from @Incomings where [Date] between i.[Date] and DATEADD(MONTH,2,i.[Date]))
from @Incomings i
```